# Is it possible to adapt a linux/windows sdk for ios?

Tags: ios, linux, windows, sdk

I recently started working on an iPhone app which needs connection to functions of a DVR. I found out that the DVR company provides SDKs for this but only for windows and linux.

So I wanted to ask if I can adapt one of these SDKs and use it for ios. The answer may be obvious and easy but with the little experience I have I want to ask the experts if it's possible. And if it is, what can be the main obstacles generally? Will porting the linux sdk to Mac, following the Apple Developer guide, help?

I can of course provide more details about the sdk if needed.

Comment: If I got a -1 because the question was stupid then sorry but it is not for me. I asked the question because I'm really stuck and wanted some advice. If I can't ask it here (where people with more experience can help me) then I don't know where to ask it. thanks anyway

Comment: URL to the SDK ? What kind of connectivity/interface does the DVR support ?

Comment: here's the url to sdk http://www.dahuasecurity.com/download_3.html